# How do i take account for the pennies in php money?

Tags: php

Ok so i have a variable named

```
$total_cost
```

which is equal to 529700

I need the value to be $5,297.00

this value is coming out of a mysql decimal 10,2 field

I need to now come up with a subtotal of 2% and a shipping of 8.25% based on whether the user is in the state

Lets just assume all the users are from this state, how would i do this via php to preserve the cents

For example this is what i was thinking

```
$subtotal = $total_cost * 0.02;
$shipping = $total_cost * 0.0825;
$new_total = $total_cost + $shipping + $subtotal;
```

but i get $0 when i print this...any ideas why

```
<?php print "$". $new_total; ?>
```

Comment: @Ignacio: +1 for Occam's razor.

Answer (score 2):

I don't obtain that result when testing your code...

```
php > $total_cost=529700;
php > $subtotal = $total_cost * 0.02;
php > $shipping = $total_cost * 0.0825;
php > $new_total = $total_cost + $shipping + $subtotal;
php > print "$". $new_total;
$583994.25
```

Are you sure that the initial value is what you expected?

Comment: @Matt - `var_dump($total_cost);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to see where this code breaks down, and that the values you think you have are actually there.... What does this output look like?

```
echo "Total: ".$total_cost."<br />";

$subtotal = $total_cost * 0.02;
echo "Sub: ".$subtotal . "<br />";

$shipping = $total_cost * 0.0825;
echo "Shipping: ".$shipping . "<br />";

$new_total = $total_cost + $shipping + $subtotal;
echo "New Total: ".$new_total . "<br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) looks like it might help you. Grab the number, divide by 100, do your calculations and format it during output.

```
<?php print "$".number_format($new_total/100, 2); ?>
```

Note that you can combine the math into a single statement:

```
$new_total = $total_cost * 1.1025; // just add the numbers together and add 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert it to a floating point number when you calculate the percentage, or the integer rounds down to 0.

```
$subtotal = $totalcost / 100.0 * 0.02;
$shipping = $totalcost / 100.0 * 0.0825;
$newtotal = $totalcost / 100.0 + $subtotal + $shipping;
```